# Without usage of external APIs or plugins, i need a single JSON with entire countries , states , cities names and ISO 3166 country codes and pin codes

Tags: forms

I am trying to use this JSON to get County name , state name and city name and pincode inside a form. I am trying to display a dropdown of all the related data for the user to select. Example : if a person selects India , Indian States should be available in the dropdown and so on..

I tried finding data from kaggle , but i dont have pin codes in that JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It isn't very clear where exactly you're getting this data from nor what this "JSON" refers to.  Please explain in detail what it is you're doing and with what code.   What is this form you're referring to?

Comment: What is a "pincode" in this context?